# ASP.NET Core 2.2 + IIS: Where can I see logs (ILogger) for my app in IIS on server?

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I using ASP.NET Core built-in logger provider (ILogger), but can't understood where can I see logs on a remote IIS server

Comment: [Logging in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: This seems very opinion-based. You as the programmer have the option of where you would like logs to be. The program does not lock you to one single form of logging / output

Comment: I mean exactly built-in Asp.net core logger. Is it possible to log on remote IIS server using built-in logger in asp.net core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends which loggers you use. The default console logger doesn't create persistent logs.
You can use Windows Event Log, or add 3rd party loggers like [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) to have persistent logs.

See the documentation on logging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

At the bottom of the page it talks about the built in loggers. But other 3rd party loggers are also available. You can use multiple loggers.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a way to see log output from my ASP.NET Core 6.0 app in a file. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#built-in-logging-providers):
ASP.NET Core doesn't include a logging provider for writing logs to files. To write logs to files from an ASP.NET Core app, consider using a third-party logging provider.

However, we found that we could write logs to a file by using the Console provider:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddConsole();
    });
```

and enabling stdoutLoging in the web.config:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myapp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

Not sure if this is the best long term approach but it will help with some quick troubleshooting. If you try this make sure the folder you're writing to exists and IIS_IUSRS has write access.